# SSRS bar-chart do not show the x-axis name when value is zero

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, reporting-services, sql

We have a Dashboard implemented by `SSRS` in `SharePoint 2010` and data source is a SharePoint list. We have a bar table in which the x-axis is month  but when data is zero it doesn't show the month name on x-axis.

What should I do to show the name of the month?

Answer (score 0):

If there are too many data bars than labels will not show.

To fix this, under the "**Chart Axis**" properties set the Interval value to "**=1**". Then all the labels will be shown.

Comment: @maria, is it working for you?